# How to map each Pixel to Vertex effectively with OpenGL ES on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, three.js, shader

Basically, I am trying to build some effect like that on iOS with GLSL.
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_kinect

With what I know, the first step should be create one vertex for each pixel, and then map each vertex with pixel. If this step done, I can adjust the z position of vertex in vertexShader with some logic, then accomplish this effect.

The problem is too slow,such as the front camera is 2MP, there will be 2M vertices in the array.

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, // bottom left
    1.0f, -1.0f, // bottom right
    -1.0f,  1.0f, // top left
    1.0f,  1.0f, // top right
};

static const float textureVertices[] = {
   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
   0.0f,  1.0f, // top left
   1.0f,  1.0f, // top right
};

glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( ATTRIB_VERTEX );
glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON );
```

Are there any GL api can do this easily and fast? 
I am guessing the key might be in THREE.BufferGeometry() and THREE.Points() 
How did three.js made that?

Comment: Do you really need a vertex per pixel? Also note that the MP of the camera might be much higher than the pixel count of the screen, so you need to take that into account. Can you get away with a fullscreen quad and a fancy fragment shader? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, its not necessary to have one for each, but should have enough number to have nice picture.  I am using the front camera of iPad, so it should be 2M.  I am try find out the correct way to make that effect, but that's the only way glVertexAttribPointer I know. I am wandering whether there are other method to do that. @BrendanAnnable

Comment: if that is the effect you want you should look at point-clouds.